# Selenium Python - Quit if Basic Auth requested

Tags: python, selenium

I have a script that collects a screenshot of a web site using Selenium. My issue is that if a site requests basic authentication I would like the script to just error and quit.

At the moment it just sits there for about a minute and then takes a blank screen shot.

The code I am using is below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
browser.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```

I am hoping that there is an easy way of making the script after the browser.get command to error if asked for authentication.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

May be not loaded this page after then selenium do screenshot. Could you use explicit waits function? For example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0

ff = webdriver.Firefox()
ff.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(ff, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement")))
finally:
    ff.quit()
```

This example quoted from [this page](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html).

Comment: The main issue is that I do not know any elements on the page until I visit it. I have added a 10 second timeout on the script but would prefer to provide more information of why it the error occurred rather than it just timed out.

Comment: So, Do you want to screenshoot this minute when authetication error occured?